# Tapping on the “Close” button when viewing a deleted user doesn’t close the view

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, deleted-accounts

When I tap on a deleted user’s profile link in the app, it shows an error dialog, then keeps the view open with the loading indicator even after I press the close button on the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in 1.4.4.3.

We were actually doing this in one screen, the site level profile that comes off of the network level one.  I've added this behavior to the network level profile and the iPad profile.